# How can I have Meteor add an attribute to many template links?

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to add an attribute to many external links.  The below code worked prior to Blaze, which only runs `Template.rendered` once now (but the below code doesn't run as desired one time even).

So what is an alternative way to add an attribute to *many* links once the page has been rendered or what is the correct way to do this with Meteor now?  BTW, I researched quite a few things, including this [example app from the author](https://github.com/avital/meteor-ui-new-rendered-callback/blob/master/new2/client/each.js), which if it has the answer, I didn't see it.

```
Template.layout.rendered = function () {
  console.log('CALLED');                  // runs
  $(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('NOW THIS');              // runs
    $('a.external').each(function () {
      console.log('NOT CALLED');          // doesn't run
      $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to deal with this problem, none of them is perfect. It's worth noting that this issue has been raised and most likely it will be solved via a custom event as proposed [here](https://meteor.hackpad.com/Blaze-Proposals-for-v0.2-hsd54WPJmDV).

For now, the simplest way to do this is to move each element you need to adjust to a separate template. So instead of:

```
<template name="layout">
  {{#each links}}
    <a class="external" ...>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

You will have:

```
<template name="layout">
  {{#each links}}
    {{> layout_externalLink}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="layout_externalLink">
  <a class="external" ...>
</template>
```

Comment: Hmm, that's quite a bummer, because we also need to have the ability to add Twitter button to articles which also require something similar to what I asked about.

Comment: You should be able to do this by extending this pattern. Or you can wait for the Blaze update.